# Modify installer package so it installs to another directory, methods?

Tags: macos, install, open-source, package-management

I want to install parts or the whole content of a preexisting open source package to another directory than what the package is set to. I assume this means I need to modify the package, correct? At least I'm not aware of a way to redirect the installation path when installing.

If a modification is necessary as I assume it is, how can do that? Is there a tool that can open a preexisting package and allow you to make changes for the install path? I'm not overly familiar with the command line tools of Xcode, but they do seem geared towards starting with the source code, rather than modifying an existing installer.

I don't really need to achieve any other resulting changes than to get my paths and likely modify permissions on installed files. But the modifications may be more involved considering postinstallation scripts and so on.

I've looked at the [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) app and that seems great for building an installer from scratch, but I haven't found a way to import a preexisting package.

Comment: What open source software?

Comment: The open source package is Nodejs, but it's a general question. Specifically I want to install into "~/usr/local" rather than "/usr/local". The reason for that is I don't want to use sudo to run installed tools, nor do I want to modify permissions in "/usr/local/".

Comment: The reason I asked in most open source code is setup to be relocatable.  Also in this case in addition to the installation package there are separate 32 bit and 64 bit versions in gzipped tar archives available.  You could use one of those, they don't have complete paths from root, or use something like Pacifist to unarchive  the package to some other location.

Comment: There's also a tool called [Payload Extractor](http://hactheplanet.com/mac/payloadextractor), I believe that will allow you to extract the contents of those packages to another location.

Comment: @DavidKoontz OK, but extraction not an install make, no? Checking out Payload Extractor. Maybe it does exactly what I want.

Comment: No, Payload Extractor seems to just be able to do what Pacifist already offers, that is to extract the files. I'll have to mimic what the package does by running post-install scripts or doing someting similar by hand. 

I asked Nodejs to make the installation path optional. That would solve that case.